# $X \in \mathcal{L}^1 \iff \lim_{K \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>K\}} =0$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Let $X$ be a random variable. A well-know result related to the definition of uniform integrability is that
\begin{align}
X \in \mathcal{L}^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}) \iff \lim_{K \to \infty}\mathbb{E}|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>K\}} = 0.
\end{align}
I face some difficulties while proving this result.

$(=>)$ By the monotone converging theorem with increasing sequence $(\mathbb{E}|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq K\}})_{K \in \mathbb{N}}$ we find that
\begin{align}
\lim_{K \to \infty} \mathbb{E}|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\leq K\}} = \mathbb{E}|X|.
\end{align}
Therefore, for all $\epsilon >0,\  \exists K >0$ such that $\mathbb{E}|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|\geq K\}} < \epsilon$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\lim_{K \to \infty}\mathbb{E}|X|\mathbb{1}_{\{|X|>K\}} = 0.
\end{align} 
Is this correct? How do I use the fact that $X \in \mathcal{L}^1$?

And how to prove $(<=)$?

Comment: For the first implication I would say it is not very clear after you say:"Therefore... ", you need to justify a bit more the results. For example where did you use the fact that X is integrable? Standard approach for that is $|X| 1_{|X|>K} \leq |X|$ and use dominated convergence theorem. For the other implication you can argue that $E|X| = E|X|1_{|X|>K} + E|X|1_{|X|\leq K}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[\Rightarrow]$ You have $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|X|1_{\{|X|> k\}}=0\;\;\text{ a.s.}$$ and $|X|1_{\{|X|> k\}}\leq |X|\in L^1$, so by the Dominated Convergence Theorem, $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}E[|X|1_{\{|X|> k\}}]=0.$$

$[\Leftarrow]$ You can take $k>0$ such that $E[|X|1_{\{|X|> k\}}]<1$. Then $$E[|X|]=E[|X|1_{\{|X| \leq k\}}]+E[|X|1_{\{|X|> k\}}]<k+1<\infty.$$